# migrate C/C++ code "typedef struct" to python

Tags: python

i have a question:

I try to programing an ANT algorithm on python but I have a code on C++, and i don't know how to programing this part:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} cityType;

typedef struct {
    int curCity;
    int nextCity;
                       //MAX_CITIES
    unsigned char tabu[15];
    int pathIndex;
                       //MAX_CITIES
    unsigned char path[15];
    double tourLength;
} antType;
```

I programing this, but i am not realy sure

```
class CityType:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = arange(MAX_CITIES)
        self.y = arange(MAX_CITIES)

# Class AntType
class AntType:
    def __init__(self):
        self.curCity = arange(MAX_ANTS)
        self.nextCity = arange(MAX_ANTS)
        self.tabu = arange(MAX_ANTS)
        self.pathIndex = arange(MAX_ANTS)
        self.path = arange(MAX_ANTS)
        self.tourLength = arange(MAX_ANTS)
```

Thanks

Comment: am I supposed to know what an ANT algorithm is? What is an ANT algorithm?

Comment: @tiwo: Relax, it's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html Implied `from foo import arange` statements not shown on SO make things challenging.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing really wrong with that. But in trying to do a word-by-word translation, you are not using the full power and conveniance that Python offers.

For example, if CityType has only two members, `x` and `y`, maybe just a tuple of length two is more pythonic. The [NamedTuple](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) provides access to tuple members "by name".

Comment: Hi tiwo, thanks for your answer in this moment i am changing my code, if its ok i will tell you about it. thanks